# All UK phone number regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex that checks all UK numbers. Almost all UK numbers are 11 digits but there are some numbers in the UK that have 10 digits beginning with 08.

Examples of the non working numbers are here:

> 0800 757757 , 0800 200400 , 0800 444252,  0870 591 285.

How can I extend this regex to check for the 10 digit numbers above as well?

Here is the regex:
`^(((\+44\s?\d{4}|\(?0\d{4}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|((\+44\s?\d{3}|\(?0\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|((\+44\s?\d{2}|\(?0\d{2}\)?)\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}))(\s?\#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?$`

Comment: And what **pattern** does your current regex match ?

Comment: For those who answer this question, [here are the formats for UK numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_the_United_Kingdom#Format)

Comment: Please post valid and invalid numbers for both categories, 08 and non 08. Also do you need to capture country code too?

Comment: Are you aware of the [libphonenumber NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/libphonenumber-csharp/)? Probably better than a regex, unless you have some desparate need to use a regex?

Comment: Numbers such as `0800 757757 , 0800 200400 , 0800 444252, 0870 591 285` could be matched by this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/jE5gY1/1). Now comes the part of collaborating it with your current regex. Or form and entirely new regex.

Comment: @4castle: Where are `11 digit` numbers ?

Comment: All UK code are on this link: http://www.area-codes.org.uk/full-uk-area-code-list.php    there international number is 0044 or +44 which replaces the 1st 0

Comment: Noob i dont mind to extend it or have a new regex. Do you have any solution ?

Comment: @noob You will notice if you count the digits that the table headers are actually off by one. I think they are ignoring the 0 at the beginning of all valid phone numbers.

Comment: @4castle: **Ignorance wont be a bliss here.** :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, for matching and validating pasterns as listed [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_the_United_Kingdom#Format), you'll need to write a very complex regex. However, for simple case as you listed above, try

```
(08(00(\s*\d\s*){3,6}|7(\s*\d\s*){7}))
```

Based on your sample numbers, it will match

```
0800 757757 
0800 200400 
0800 444252
0870 591 285
```

Comment: This regex took 140 steps. While [this](https://regex101.com/r/jE5gY1/1) took 40. Which one do you prefer ?

Comment: you win! :) I wasn't after optimization but just proof of concept.

Comment: Actually, I was trying to implement scheme mentioned in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_the_United_Kingdom#Format, so there are alot of ifs and buts.

Comment: Yea it's going to be a long night.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what particular problem you are trying to solve but here's my 5 pence.

If you are trying to validate a user input then your approach is as wrong as [validating an email address](https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/). What if a user enters a (perfectly valid!) number of his ex-partner just for fun? Or accidentally mistypes a last digit? How are you going to deal with numbers with suffixes to bypass swichboards to connect directly to the person like `020 11112222,,1234` where `1234` is an extension number?

If you really need to be sure a given number is valid and belong to a particular user then send a text with some unique number and ask a user to re-enter that number later.

---

If, on the other hand, you are trying to grab phone numbers from some text then you will never be 100% accurate. Handling all cases in a single regex will be extremely hard if at all possible. You will need to handle numbers such as `+44(0)20 xxxx yyyy`, `44 020 xxxxyyyyy` etc. etc. Be prepared to get both false positives and negatives.